# How to switch to the Git flow?

Tags: git, git-flow

I have a fairly long git log with a main `master` branch. We wants to switch to the Git flow where there are three working branches:

- develop
- release
- feature

The easy way to migrate is to rename the master branch `release` and create the `develop` branch on the top of it.

```
$ git checkout -b develop
$ git checkout -b release
$ git branch -D master
```

I find this solution is not very clean for several reasons:

- The master cannot disappear on the remote branch unless all the developers are aware to prune their repositories
- The `develop` branch should be an orphan one since all the work before its creation does not belong to it. In this case, the tree-way-merge will be difficult

What is the proper way to adopt the Git Flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly new to git myself, but...

How about creating `develop` from `master` and **starting the new workflow from there**? Do you absolutely have to alter your branches?

If using `git flow` is an option, check this out: http://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/. It will help handle all the branching must easily.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly easy: just run `gitflow init` after installing `sudo apt install git-flow` in the repo directory.

Please find References [here](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/wiki/FAQ).